# Am using to update the multiple rows in laravel but it give me error

Tags: php, laravel-5

```
public function productUpdate(Request $request)
{

    $product_id = $request->product_id;
    $new_weight = $request->new_weight;
    $id = array();
    $name = array();
    $query ='';
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($product_id); $i++) {
        $id = $product_id[$i];

        $name = $new_weight[$i];
        if($name != 0){

            // $query .= DB::statement("UPDATE acc_products SET prodweight = '$name' WHERE productid = '$id';")->toSql();
            DB::table('acc_products')->where('productid', $id)->update(['prodweight'=>$name])->toSql();

         }

    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain what error you are getting and what is value of $product_id this variable.

Comment: Have you checked that the request contains the data you expect and that you have products that matches those id's?

Comment: Am updating these values in db with rest api in laravel but when i use update query it give me error woops something went wrong the vaue of product_id can be in array actuaaly i want to update multipple rows

Comment: Thanks its done there is issue in database name and password

Answer (score 0):

Updated Code

```
public function productUpdate(Request $request)
{    
    $product_id = $request->product_id;
    $new_weight = $request->new_weight;
    $id = array();
    $name = array();
    $query ='';
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($product_id); $i++) {
        $id = $product_id[$i];    
        $name = $new_weight[$i];
        if($name != 0){
        DB::table('acc_products')->where('productid', $id)->update(['prodweight'=>$name]);    
         }    
    }
}
```